# можно ли вывести программным методом в файл?

Tags: winapi

можно перехватить URL сайты в браузере и записать его в txt

интернет-браузеры mozilla и chrome

Comment: А более подробней?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, стоит задача: написать ПО которое будет логировать посещаемые сайты браузеров mozilla и chrome. Если быть точнее, считыванием именно этого поля.

Comment: Метод должен быть как я полагаю через WinAPI(хуки). Зная его хендел и id. Но мне тут сказали, что не всё так просто. В общем гуру помогите. Как можно считать это поле?

Comment: Ну вот это все вам надо объяснять не мне, а сообществу в самом вопросе. Так что пожалуйста, перенесите это все в вопрос и предоставьте как можно больше информации для понимания, ибо сейчас у вас просто картинка и набор браузеров, это не вопрос...

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить вопрос? перехватить url когда вы серфите и-нет? Или когда вы перешли на определенные страницы? Или другой вариант?

Comment: Вариант: написать (найти) расширения для браузеров (для каждого свое). Другой вариант: использовать pcap для перехвата траффика.